# Do I get to keep medals/fruit if I quit out of a level?

Tags: kirby-mass-attack

I'm going to need to do some backtracking to get my Rainbow medals. If I get a medal and quit out of a level do I get to keep that medal or will I keep it? I know I get a "you'll lose progress" message but different games interpret "lose progress" differently so I don't really know if I'll still have that medal unlocked (and I haven't been brave enough to try it).

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to finish the level to get the medals.